# How to handle triangle-shaped scatterplot of data?

Tags: regression, zero-inflation, scatterplot, dispersion

Over the past year, I have tried to record my productivity in the following way:

[image]

The first yellow mark is the time I "clock in", or start working for the day. For the five minutes of work produced during that time (8:00 am to 8:05 am), I record that as the minutes of actual work accomplished. The second yellow marker is when I "clock out" or finish working for the day. I then total all of the minutes together (5 + 30 + 30 = 65 minutes) to record how much work I actually accomplished during that time. This produces essentially three variables:

- Start_Work: when I clock in
- End_Work: when I clock out
- Mins_Work: minutes of productivity

Today I checked what the relationship is between End_Work and Mins_Work, and it has a Spearman correlation of $\rho = .55$. The density plots of both variables look like this:

[image]

Running a scatterplot and a regression line on the data looks like this...which appears to resemble a triangle:

[image]

This seems to make sense to a degree. There are days like Sunday where I either don't work or work very little, which creates the bounded section on the bottom and the weird shape of it's associated density plot. It is also impossible to work past midnight in a single day, so this creates the bounded section on the right. Together, this makes a weird triangle shape of the data.

With this in mind, I feel like there are obvious issues with where the data is dispersed. How would one appropriately model this data in a simple regression? I know that one method is to use a zero-inflated regression, but given both variables are bounded, would that still be okay to use?

##### Edit

For reference, this is what the relationship looks like if plotted against clock-in time, which looks like it has its own issues of unequal variance:

[image]

Comment: It might be interesting to show a (small multiples) plot by day of week. Another relevant split might be holidays or not. And isn't it more "natural" to have x = clock-in time? Won't that avoid the working past midnight issue?

Comment: I have that data too, but it also appears pretty strange. I have edited it into the question for reference. The main thing is I want to test whether or not working late is really predictive of how much work gets done, as it is a common practice in my office. Of course this is data of myself, so it is limited, but I was just curious after looking at it. I do have daily/monthly data. What specifically do you mean by small multiples?

Comment: The clock-in time version seems "easier" to reason about. For example, it's a bit more clear that the variance is a function of when you start work. (Starting later probably means less productivity with smaller variance). So make the variance a function of time?

Comment: Small multiples, or facets in the ggplot2 language. https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html (Now I wonder who came up with the term first.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I know what a faceted plot is then. I'm more curious about how to model this into a regression.